# Set inital state of react component with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am currently trying to enhance my projekt with a few react components.
I have managed to build the app and it does what I want.

Now I need to get rid of the dummy array which contains some data and fill it with real data form my database.

Usually I'd do it with ajax and parse it out.

I have checked the facebook documentation and I've found the following code snippet :

```
...    
componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
          var lastGist = result[0];
          if (this.isMounted()) {
            this.setState({
              username: lastGist.owner.login,
              lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
            });
          }
        }.bind(this));
      },
...
```

Now my question is, how and when should this function be called in a react component. Or is it a saved name and gets called automatically?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it a saved name and gets called automatically?

**Yes.**

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount